# change property of rad controls in form

Tags: c#, telerik, rad-controls

How can I access a property of rad controls in my form. something like code bellow

```
foreach (Control ctrl in this.Controls)
  {
   RadControl rc = ctrl as RadControl;
    if (rc != null)
       {
           if (rc.GetType() == typeof(Telerik.WinControls.UI.RadButton))
            {
              rc.Image = ....
            }
     }
 }
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

In your conditional statement you want to test `if (ctrl is RadControl)`

And you want to make this into a recursive function that will go down through all Control collections in the page.

```
private void DoSomethingToRadControls(ControlCollection controls) {
  if (controls != null && controls.Any()) {
    foreach (Control ctrl in controls) {
      if (ctrl is RadControl) {
        // do something
      }
      DoSomethingToRadControls(ctrl.Controls);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for reply, but it dosent work . radcontrol button has a property (image). in  this state                                     if (ctrl is RadControl) { ctrl.Image = ...  }                         ctrl has no property as Image . and I cant access image property of a control

Comment: what happens when you try it?

Comment: test this =>  private void DoSomethingToRadControls(ControlCollection controls) {
              if (controls != null ) {
               foreach (Control ctrl in controls) {
               if (ctrl is RadControl) {
                   ctrl.Image = ...
                }
                   

                 }
                  }
             }

Comment: just a thought, but maybe try casting ctrl as RadButton? i.e. `(RadButton)rc.Image = ...`